# How to know when the effect is done within effect in ngrx component store (rxjs flow)?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, ngrx-store

I'm currently implementing a feature that "open a dialog"(effect), after the dialog open the user hit save and then I want to close the dialog.

I made fake dialog and flow for the example.

I also split the flow into two effects: `openDialogEffect` and `saveEffect` to avoid "operator-hell" and code more readable and reuse save effect from another calls.

this works fine. until I want to close the dialog AFTER the save is successful.
The problem is how to "hook" into the pipeline of `saveEffect`?

I reproduce the problem here: [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-2oxbby?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.service.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts)

```
readonly openDialogEffect = this.effect(($: Observable<any>) =>
    $.pipe(
      exhaustMap((dialogRef) =>
        dialogRef.open().pipe(
          tap({
            next: () => {
              this.saveEffect(); // <----- after that need to close the dialog... but how??
              // then: dialogRef.close();
            },
          })
        )
      )
    )
  );

  readonly saveEffect = this.effect(($) =>
    $.pipe(
      exhaustMap(() =>
        this.api.save().pipe(
          switchMap((res) =>
            this.api.updateFoo(res).pipe(
              tap({
                next: () => {
                  console.log('after save');
                  this.toast.success();
                },
                error: () => {
                  console.log('in error');
                  this.toast.error();
                },
              })
            )
          )
        )
      )
    )
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

ngrx is able to handle pure side effects (effects that does not manipulate application state). Although you need to dispatch action from within an effect to achieve that, otherwise you can't be sure if it was successful or not.

```
@Component({
  // component metadata
})
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(
    private readonly actions$: Actions,
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(someAction),
      takeUntil(this.destroy$), // remember to unsubscribe
    ).subscribe(({payload}) => {
      // show toast
      // close dialog
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a callback and passing to **saveEffect** through **openDialogEffect**:

the callback could be:

1. function
2. custom rxjs operator

---

***1. using function callback***

[function callback](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-n8d52o?file=src/app/app.service.ts)

```
@Injectable()
export class AppService extends ComponentStore<State> {
  readonly openDialogEffect = this.effect<{
    // new code
    whenSaved: () => void;
    dialogRef;
  }>((arg$) =>
    arg$.pipe(
      exhaustMap(({ whenSaved, dialogRef }) =>
        dialogRef.open().pipe(
          tap({
            next: () => {
              this.saveEffect({
                whenSaved,
              });
              // then: dialogRef.close();
            },
          })
        )
      )
    )
  );

  readonly saveEffect = this.effect<{
    // new codes
    whenSaved: () => void;
  }>((arg$) =>
    arg$.pipe(
      exhaustMap((arg) =>
        this.api.save().pipe(
          switchMap((res) =>
            this.api.updateFoo(res).pipe(
              tap({
                next: () => {
                  console.log('after save');
                  arg.whenSaved();
                  this.toast.success();
                },
                error: () => {
                  console.log('in error');
                  this.toast.error();
                },
              })
            )
          )
        )
      )
    )
  );

  constructor(private api: ApiService, private toast: ToastrService) {
    super();

    this.openDialogEffect(
      of({
        dialogRef: dialog,
        whenSaved: () => {
          console.log('saved!!');
        },
      })
    );
  }
}
```

---

***2. using custom rxjs operator***

[custom rxjs operator](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-y4kpxv?file=src/app/app.service.ts)

```
@Injectable()
export class AppService extends ComponentStore<State> {
  readonly openDialogEffect = this.effect<{
    // new code
    whenSaved$: () => MonoTypeOperatorFunction<unknown>;
    dialogRef;
  }>((arg$) =>
    arg$.pipe(
      exhaustMap(({ whenSaved$, dialogRef }) =>
        dialogRef.open().pipe(
          tap({
            next: () => {
              this.saveEffect({
                whenSaved$,
              });
              // then: dialogRef.close();
            },
          })
        )
      )
    )
  );

  readonly saveEffect = this.effect<{
    // new codes
    whenSaved$: () => MonoTypeOperatorFunction<unknown>;
  }>((arg$) =>
    arg$.pipe(
      exhaustMap((arg) =>
        this.api.save().pipe(
          switchMap((res) =>
            this.api.updateFoo(res).pipe(
              tap({
                next: () => {
                  console.log('after save');
                  this.toast.success();
                },
                error: () => {
                  console.log('in error');
                  this.toast.error();
                },
              }),
              arg.whenSaved$()
            )
          )
        )
      )
    )
  );

  constructor(private api: ApiService, private toast: ToastrService) {
    super();

    this.openDialogEffect(
      of({
        dialogRef: dialog,
        whenSaved$: () => {
          return function <T>(source: Observable<T>): Observable<T> {
            return source.pipe(
              tap((isSaved) => console.log('save!', isSaved)),
              tap(() => console.log('do some thing...'))
            );
          };
        },
      })
    );
  }
}
```